# How would I prevent redirecting of a href during touchmove and mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I've got an issue while I'm trying to combine `touchstart` and `mousedown` in 1 function. I've used an `a` tag as the target element of the function for going to the link directly when I touched or clicked the tag.

The issue is when I `touch` the middle of `a` tag, link doesn't respond. it only works when I `click` the element or **touch the edge of the `a` tag**, and the output fires `mousedown`.

[image]

In the mobile mode, try to click the edge of `a` tag as much as you would possible like a grey dot in the picture above. I've created an [CodePen](https://codepen.io/o22/pen/jJJPLV) example for looking, testing and understanding better.

How would I fix this issue?

```js
class Slider {
  constructor($el, paragraph) {
    this.$el = $el;
    this.paragraph = paragraph;
  }
  start(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var type = e.type;
    if (type === 'touchstart' || type === 'mousedown') this.paragraph.text(this.paragraph.text() + ' ' + type);
    return false;
  }
  apply() {
    this.$el.bind('touchstart mousedown', (e) => this.start(e));
  }
}
const setSlider = new Slider($('#anchor'), $('.textbox'), {passive: false});
setSlider.apply();
```

```css
  a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
  }
```

```html
<a id="anchor" href="https://google.co.uk">Tap or Click Me</a>
<p class="textbox"></p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

========= Progress Update ==========

I've just added `move` & `end` function then I have to click twice for moving on to the linked website. It keeps getting worse and have no idea how to solve this issue.

```
class Slider {
  constructor($el, paragraph) {
    this.$el = $el;
    this.paragraph = paragraph;
  }
  start(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var type = e.type;
    if (type === 'touchstart' || type === 'mousedown') this.paragraph.text(this.paragraph.text() + ' ' + type);
    this.$el.bind('touchmove mousemove', (e) => this.move(e));
    this.$el.bind('touchend mouseup', (e) => this.end(e));
    return false;
  }
  move(e) {
    var type = e.type;
    if (type === 'touchstart' || type === 'mousedown') this.paragraph.text(this.paragraph.text() + ' ' + type);
    return false;
  }
  end(e) {
    console.log('test');
    this.$el.on('click');
    this.$el.off('touchstart touchend');
    return false;
  }
  apply() {
    this.$el.bind('touchstart || mousedown', (e) => this.start(e));

  }
}
const setSlider = new Slider($('#anchor'), $('.textbox'));
setSlider.apply();
```

======== Progress Updated After Bounty (Latest) ========

After dozens of tried, I've finally figured out and solve the previous problem but I've faced up a new issue that can't draggable and redirecting instantly.

When I use the `preventDefault` in the start function, all of the events work fine. The only issue of this case is **dragging doesn't prevent redirecting link from the `a` tag**. It always send me to the website no matter which ways to call the functions, clicked or dragged.

when I don't use the `preventDefault`, dragging doesn't work. it only works clicking the elements.

My final goal is to prevent redirecting link of the `a` tag from the both events, `touchmove` and `mousemove`. I've been searched about on google so many times but haven't got any of the clues.

I've written an example in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/o22/pen/aMgopm) and this is what I've done so far:

```js
class Slider {
  constructor($el, paragraph) {
    this.$el = $el;
    this.paragraph = paragraph;
  }
  start(e) {
    var type = e.type;
    if (type === 'touchstart') {
      this.paragraph.text(this.paragraph.text() + ' ' + type);
    } else if (type === 'mousedown') {
      this.paragraph.text(this.paragraph.text() + ' ' + type);
    }
  }
  move(e) {
    var type = e.type;
  }
  end(e) {
    var type = e.type;
    if (type === 'touchend') {
      console.log('touchstart enabled');
    } else if (type === 'mouseup') {
      console.log('mousedown enabled');
    }
  }
  apply() {
    this.$el.bind({
      touchstart: (e) => this.start(e),
      touchmove: (e) => this.move(e),
      touchend: (e) => this.end(e),
      mousedown:(e) => this.start(e),
      onmousemove: (e) => this.move(e),
      mouseup:  (e) => this.end(e)
    });
  }
}
const setSlider = new Slider($('#anchor'), $('.textbox'));
setSlider.apply();
```

```css
    a {
      display: block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: orange; 
    }
```

```html
    <a id="anchor" href="https://google.co.uk">Tap or Click Me</a>
    <p class="textbox"></p>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The codepen mentioned above seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: @varunagarwal Does it change your browser to google when you touch the middle of `a` tag?

Comment: Yes it does and I also see the `mousedown` being appended below the box.

Comment: @varunagarwal Do you using Firefox? Then I think you should use Chrome to know my issue more clearly. I've just tested in Firefox and it shows me the `mousedown` text.

Comment: @varunagarwal Yeah, in Firefox `touchevent` works fine what I expected. It takes me to google when I touched the middle of `a` tag as the Mobile statement. But in Chrome, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using chrome.

Comment: @varunagarwal Huh, then That's weird.

Comment: why dont you just remove the anchor tag, and use javascript redirect instead where it is needed. worth a try.

Comment: @Galzor Then I should put each every links where I want to redirect the websites, such as `link1: aaa`, `link2: bbb` ... and for me this case looks dirty. There would be another solutions to optimize it but I still don't like this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found the solution about this. I add this code for some people in the future who are trying hard to search the same problem such as me.

```js
    function start(event, etype, condition) {
      console.log(etype); // track the type of event
      if (!condition) event.preventDefault(); // compare etype(eventType). Set preventDefault if condition is falsy.
      items.off('click');
      items.on({
        ['touchmove mousemove']: (event) => move(event, etype, condition),
        ['touchend mouseup']: end
      });
    }

    function move(event, etype, cnd) {
      if (cnd) event.preventDefault();
      console.log(cnd); // track the type of event from the condition
      items.on('click', function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
    }

    function end(event) {
      items.off('touchmove mousemove touchend mouseup');
    }
    var items = $('.item a');
    items.on('touchstart mousedown', function() {
      var eventType = event.type;
      var condition = (eventType === 'touchstart' || eventType === 'mousedown');
      start(event, eventType, condition);
    });
```

```css
    #anchor {
      display: block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: orange;
    }
    .item {
    background-color: gray;
    }

    .item + .item {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .item a {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        padding: 9px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="items" class="items">
      <div class="item">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Anchor</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Anchor</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: glad you find the solution and thank you for sharing. it ll surely help people looking for something similar.

Comment: @Galzor You're welcome Glazor, or someone who will find this solution in near future.

Answer (score 4):

i think i figured out little solution for you. enable the preventDefault and afterwards enable the draggable for the a tag. Let me know if this works for you.

```
 start(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...//rest of the code
 apply() {
  $el.draggable("enable");
  ...//rest of the code
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but this doesn't work for me.